# Rate limit for YouTube Live Streaming API (Live Chat Messages)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am writing a chat bot for my channel.  It has six webcams and adding more soon.  The bot will enable viewers to move the cameras around and take snapshots by entering commands into the live chat.  However, for this to work well, I need to query the API every few seconds.  I'm concerned that I will run into rate limits.  I found a page with a calculator but it doesn't have any of the live chat API calls listed.  Is there a rate limit to call the YouTube Live Streaming API (Live Chat Messages)?

thank you in advance

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, indeed I have ran into it. I have just found this page which might help. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota